# Custom diff output from a shell task in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am making an ansible task which needs some custom logic, so I'm writting a little shell script and using the `shell` task. Is there anyway I can output any sort of "diff" output to display to the user if they are using `--diff`? I know about using `-vv` to look at the stdout & stderr of the script, but that's not formatted well, and you get lots of extra output too

Ansible version 2.9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you would need to write a custom module, not simply a custom script. The `command` and `shell` modules do not have any provision for returning custom attributes based on command output.

Custom Python modules are fairly easy to write and can be placed in a `library` directory adjacent to your playbook or within a role (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally).  You can also write custom modules as bash scripts and deploy them the same way, but you'll miss out on a lot of the convenience functions available to Python modules for things like argument validation.

Here's a quick and dirty bash module that returns a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $1
jq -n -r \
    --arg contents "$(cat $src)"\
    '{ changed: false, result: $contents }'
```

Or some fairly equivalent Python:

```
!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule


def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = {
            'src': {
                'required': True,
                'type': 'path',
            }
        }
    )

    with open(module.params['src'], 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()

    module.exit_json(changed=False, result=contents)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```